# Chrome/Opera `window.onpopstate` bug

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, opera, html5-history

I'm trying to handle `window.onpopstate` event in my single page app and in Google Chrome and Opera it doesn't work.

This is my simple html page

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script>
        window.onpopstate = function(e) {
            alert('onpopstate');
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            history.pushState(1, 'Hello John', '/hello/john');
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            history.pushState(2, 'Hello Emily', '/hello/emily');
        }, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

When I hit browser's back button I expect to see alert with `onpopstate` text to be shown. In Safari, Firefox, Vivaldi it works as expected. In Chrome and Opera it never called, it is just going to previous page by reloading it which is bad scenario for my SPA.

What is more weird is that I found some trick to make it work:

1. go to dev tools, console tab
2. simply execute `console.log(history)` or even `console.log(window)`
   and it magically starts working! But if I do the same in script on the page with or without timeout this trick doesn't work at all. So the only way to make `onpopstate` work which I found is to manually go to console and execute `console.log(history)`.

Maybe I'm missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

My environment:

- macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
- Chrome 87.0.4280.67 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Opera 72.0.3815.378

Posted [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151598)

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, this is not a bug, it is a feature! It is kinda `interact first` feature of Chromium. If user interact first somehow with a page then everything gonna work, otherwise `back button` will go back with reloading.

So e.g. just add some button into body and click on it first, then try to click `back` in browser.

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="alert('hello');">alert</button>
</body>
```

Comment: history.pushState(1, 'Hello John', '/hello/john'); throws an exception in Chrome, because 1 is not an object. Try {id:1}?

Comment: Hmmm.. I see no exceptions and Chrome successfully saves it into `history.state` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to run some javascript  like moving  on history or play sounds  or pop up windows the user first hast to interact (click) on the web site.

you can find more info here:

[WebUpdates 2017](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017)

Answer (score 0):

There's note I found on MDN. It says:

> Note: Calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't
> trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by
> performing a browser action, such as clicking on the back button (or
> calling history.back() in JavaScript), when navigating between two
> history entries for the same document.

You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

And I suggest you to register your event handler to the `addEventListener()` instead of registering it to [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) property of [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers).

**Example:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script>
            // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
                alert('onpopstate');
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                history.pushState(1, 'Hello John', '/hello/john');
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                history.pushState(2, 'Hello Emily', '/hello/emily');
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with both simple `window.onpopstate` and `window.addEventListener('popstate'` and unfortunately it doesn't work in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Object` for the `state`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the
> new history entry created by pushState(). Whenever the user navigates
> to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of
> the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

```js
const log = Logger();

// create 3 'history pages'
history.pushState({page: 1, greet: "Hello John"}, '', "#John");
history.pushState({page: 2, greet: "Hello Emily"}, '', "#Emily");
history.pushState({page: 3, greet: "Hello James"}, '', "#James");

log(`current history state: ${JSON.stringify(history.state)}`);

// on popstate log the history state if applicable
window.addEventListener("popstate", () =>
  history && history.state && log(`${history.state.greet || ""} @page ${
    history.state.page} (location: ${location.hash})`)
);

// listener for the buttons
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    return evt.target.id === "back" ? history.back() : history.forward();
  }
});

// helper function for logging in the document
function Logger() {
  let logEl;
  if (typeof window === "object") {
    logEl = document.querySelector("#log") || (() => {
      document.body.append(
        Object.assign(document.createElement('pre'), 
        {id: "log"}));
      return document.querySelector("#log");
    })();
    return (...logLines) => 
      logLines.forEach(s => logEl.textContent += `${s}\n`);
  } else {
    return (...logLines) => 
      logLines.forEach(ll => console.log(`* `, ll));
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="back">&lt;&lt; 1 back</button>
<button id="forward">1 forward &gt;&gt;</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, with custom back/forward buttons it works, but only if you click on these custom buttons first. If I try to hit back button first it just going back with reloading. And please take note that in my example I don't use hashes since there are no bug with hashes, there are a bug exactly with path without hash.

Comment: You can't hit the browser back button within the snippet. However, you can right click within the snippet result and hit 'back' or 'forward', or use the shortcut key combinations Alt-Left-Arrow and Alt-Right-Arrow. In that case the scripting in the snippet works like it should.

Comment: Thank you, but I tested it on the real server with properly configured `nginx`

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with a server or server configuration.

Comment: To test real path(not hash) configured server is needed.

Comment: In that case it probably is not the `popstate` functionality